# Pause and Resume SwingWorker.doInBackground()

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker

I have a basic Swing UI with a single button marked "Play." When the button is pressed the label changes to "Pause". When the button is pressed now it changes to say "Resume."

On "Play" I am instantiating and executing a SwingWorker. What I would like is to be able to pause this thread (NOT cancel it) and resume it according to the button presses described above. However, I'd prefer not to resort to Thread.sleep() in doInBackground(). That seems a bit hackish. Is there any way for the thread running doInBackground to block?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Pause and Resume SwingWorker.doInBackground()

First of all you have to be sure the background task being performed can be paused, otherwise the question doesn't make sense. So let's say the task can be paused, then you might extend [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) class and make your own *pausable* worker using a simple flag variable to control the background thread status: *paused* or *not paused*.

```
public abstract class PausableSwingWorker<K, V> extends SwingWorker<K, V> {

    private volatile boolean isPaused;

    public final void pause() {
        if (!isPaused() && !isDone()) {
            isPaused = true;
            firePropertyChange("paused", false, true);
        }
    }

    public final void resume() {
        if (isPaused() && !isDone()) {
            isPaused = false;
            firePropertyChange("paused", true, false);
        }
    }

    public final boolean isPaused() {
        return isPaused;
    }
}
```

Subclasses might check `isPaused()` status in order to efectively proceed with the task or not. For example:

```
PausableSwingWorker<Void, String> worker = new PausableSwingWorker<Void, String>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        while (!isCancelled()) {
            if (!isPaused()) {
                // proceed with background task
            } else {
                Thread.sleep(200); // Optional sleep to avoid check status continuously
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
};
```

You can also add a [PropertyChangeListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html) to the worker and listen for `paused` property changes:

```
worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        if ("paused".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
           System.out.println("Old status: " + evt.getOldValue());
           System.out.println("New status: " + evt.getNewValue());
        }
    }
});
```

---

#### Example (updated to make use of PropertyChangeListener)

Here is a complete example to play with. Please note that if worker is stopped then it cannot be paused nor resumed anymore.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class Demo {

    private void createAndShowGUI() {

        final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(20, 50);

        final PausableSwingWorker<Void, String> worker = new PausableSwingWorker<Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                while (!isCancelled()) {
                    if (!isPaused()) {
                        publish("Writing...");
                    } else {
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
                String text = String.format("%s%n", chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1));
                textArea.append(text);
            }
        };

        worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                if ("paused".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                    String text = (Boolean)evt.getNewValue() ? "Paused..." : "Resumed...";
                    textArea.append(String.format("%s%n", text));
                }
            }
        });

        Action pause = new AbstractAction("Pause") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                worker.pause();
            }
        };

        Action resume = new AbstractAction("Resume") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                worker.resume();
            }
        };

        Action stop = new AbstractAction("Stop") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                worker.cancel(true);
            }
        };

        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        buttonsPanel.add(new JButton(pause));
        buttonsPanel.add(new JButton(resume));
        buttonsPanel.add(new JButton(stop));

        JPanel content = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(8, 8));
        content.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(8, 8, 8, 8));
        content.add(new JScrollPane(textArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        content.add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                if (!worker.isDone()) {
                    worker.cancel(true);
                }
                e.getWindow().dispose();
            }
        });

        frame.add(content);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        worker.execute();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Demo().createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    abstract class PausableSwingWorker<K, V> extends SwingWorker<K, V> {

        private volatile boolean isPaused;

        public final void pause() {
            if (!isPaused() && !isDone()) {
                isPaused = true;
                firePropertyChange("paused", false, true);
            }
        }

        public final void resume() {
            if (isPaused() && !isDone()) {
                isPaused = false;
                firePropertyChange("paused", true, false);
            }
        }

        public final boolean isPaused() {
            return isPaused;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a fantastic and thorough answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @mKorbel:) I have updated the abstract class to include PropertyChange support for "paused" property. So now I think it's complete.

Comment: Please see my updated code. I have added PropertyChange support for "paused" property so you can listen for this property now @barkbark

Comment: I'm love firePropertyChange