# how to pause swing worker and what is chunks in swing worker

Tags: java, swingworker

Can we pause the execution of swing worker.
Does java has any methods for that.
Thanks .
also what is chunks in that 
can anyone suggest any article for that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26265002/pause-and-resume-swingworker-doinbackground

Comment: [Swingworker tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)