# How to pause, resume & stop a "Process" & "dependent thread" run within SwingWorker

Tags: java, multithreading, applet, processbuilder, swingworker

I am working on Applets where I am building a GUI like this:

[image]

I have used `SwingWorkerThread` so as to efficiently print 1000s of lines within few seconds on `JTable`. Actually from `doInBackground()` I am firing a command to capture logs, this is achieved using `Process` instance. Further there is a separate `Thread` that processes the input captured by `Process` instance.

But the problem is I am not able to implement functionality of "Pause" & "Stop" buttons. 
I have seen some posts where functionality like this has been implemented:

```
protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
while (!isCancelled()) {
    if (!isPaused()) {
        publish("Writing...");
    } else {
        Thread.sleep(200);
    }
}
return null;
```

}

Problem 1:
But difficulty in my code is `process.waitFor()` is executed only once, I cant check "paused" variable or `isCancelled()` method in loop. 
Also for the purpose of faster implementation, I have called the `publish()` method from different `Thread`s (`InputConsumer`). 
I am wondering how it is possible to pause the execution of both (`Process` & `InputStream`) threads simultaneously.

Problem 2: Implementation of "Stop" button.
The invocation of `worker.cancel(true)` doesn't stop the execution of threads created from `doInBackground()` method.

The working code with implementation of only "Run" button looks like this:

```
public class LogViewer extends javax.swing.JApplet {
    BufferedReader br;
    DefaultTableModel model;
    TableSwingWorker worker;
    @Override
    public void init() {
        try {
            //initialize GUI
            viewLogs();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void viewLogs() throws IOException{

        model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
        worker = new TableSwingWorker(model);

    }

    public class TableSwingWorker extends SwingWorker<Integer, Object[]>{
        private DefaultTableModel tableModel;
        public TableSwingWorker(DefaultTableModel tableModel){
            this.tableModel = tableModel;
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {

            String[] command = {"CMD", "/C", "adb logcat"};
            ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
            Process process = probuilder.start();

            InputConsumer consumer = new InputConsumer(process.getInputStream());
            consumer.start();

            int result = process.waitFor();
            consumer.join();

            return result;

        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<Object[]> chunks) {
            for(Object[] row: chunks)
                tableModel.addRow(row);
        }

        protected void processOutput(String text){
            //process text received
            publish(new Object[]{line, date, time, PID, TID, loglevel, tag, message});
        }

        public class InputConsumer extends Thread {
            private InputStream is;

            public InputConsumer(InputStream is){
                this.is = is;
                start();
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                try{
                    String text = null;
                    while((text = br.readLine()) != null){
                        processOutput(text);
                    }
                }
                catch(IOException ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }              
}
```

Any help on the issue will be deeply appreciated. Kindly comment for more clarification from my side.

Comment: 1) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing. 2) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).

Comment: Indentation problem corrected.

Comment: *"Indentation problem corrected."* Well, one out of two ain't bad. ;)

Comment: For the second suggestion, still would that solve the original problem?

Comment: *"For the second suggestion"* No, you misunderstood. When I wrote *"Well, one out of two ain't bad."* I meant you'd only correctly fixed one of the hanging close brackets. As to.. *"still would that solve the original problem?"* No, my 2nd point means applets are screwed. Do something productive.

Comment: Btw, got the code running by restructuring SwingWorkerThread using the suggestion provided in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26265002/pause-and-resume-swingworker-doinbackground
PropertyChangeListener did the trick.